# Zoom WebSDK 404 errors

Tags: angular, zoom-sdk

I am integrating Zoom WebSDK 1.7.7 is in Angular 8 Application. At the top of the Angular component, after import ZoomMtg, I declared preloadWasm as below

```
import { ZoomMtg } from '@zoomus/websdk';

ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
ZoomMtg.prepareJssdk();
```

But when I run the App, I get the following error (Confirmed that these files are exist in this path)

```
zone.js:3372 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib/av/audio.encode.wasm 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:3372 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib/av/video.decode.wasm 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:3372 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib/av/video.mt.wasm 404 (Not Found)
zoomus-websdk.umd.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib/av/js_media.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
zoomus-websdk.umd.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib/webim.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue,i'm trying to run it locally. When i use the below

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is correct approach. However I am able resolve the issue by setting path before preload action

```
ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib('https://jssdk.zoomus.cn/1.7.7/lib', '/av');
ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
ZoomMtg.prepareJssdk();
```

Comment: I tried this and it only removed the first error but left the last 3?? It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added the directory to your angular.json file under assets.

```
{        
    "glob":"**/*",
    "input": "./node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib/",
    "output": "./node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib/"
}
```